# Why do "segmented" and "selgmented" functions in the package "segmented" give different outputs?

Tags: r, regression, segment, piecewise

I am using the `selgmented` function in the `segmented` package to select the number of breakpoints in a time-series regression. This function behaves as expected and provides a `segmented` object. However, if I run the same dataset using the `segmented` function with `npsi` set to the number of breakpoints determined by `selgmented`, it sometimes returns different results (i.e., different segment slopes and different breakpoints). I have tried modifying some of the parameters using `seg.control`, but I am usually unsuccessful in achieving identical results between the two functions. I am wondering what is different between these functions and why they produce different results. Usually these differences are minor, but I'd like to understand why they occur.

I have included an example using the Plant organ dataset included with the segmented package.

```
library(segmented) 

data(plant)
plant_RKV <- plant[which(plant$group=="RKV"), ]

out.lm <- lm(y ~ time, data=plant_RKV)

os <- selgmented(out.lm, type="bic", Kmax=5)
o <- segmented(out.lm, npsi=4)

> summary(os)

        ***Regression Model with Segmented Relationship(s)***

Call: 
segmented.lm(obj = olm, seg.Z = seg.Z, psi = startpsi[[i - 1]], 
    control = control1)

Estimated Break-Point(s):
              Est. St.Err
psi1.time 314.495 13.909
psi2.time 471.338 15.939
psi3.time 542.613  9.392
psi4.time 565.911  7.278

Meaningful coefficients of the linear terms:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.0694477  0.0281773   2.465    0.022 *  
time         0.0024848  0.0001249  19.895 1.49e-15 ***
U1.time     -0.0015098  0.0002187  -6.903       NA    
U2.time     -0.0030369  0.0011887  -2.555       NA    
U3.time      0.0056947  0.0022973   2.479       NA    
U4.time     -0.0043988  0.0019883  -2.212       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.02418 on 22 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-Squared: 0.9856,  Adjusted R-squared: 0.9798 

Convergence attained in 3 iterations (rel. change 2.3914e-10)

> summary(o)

        ***Regression Model with Segmented Relationship(s)***

Call: 
segmented.lm(obj = out.lm, npsi = 4)

Estimated Break-Point(s):
              Est. St.Err
psi1.time 295.723 16.654
psi2.time 458.156 11.044
psi3.time 544.410  8.446
psi4.time 566.120  7.659

Meaningful coefficients of the linear terms:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.0497251  0.0359206   1.384     0.18    
time         0.0025961  0.0001788  14.522  9.4e-13 ***
U1.time     -0.0014525  0.0002439  -5.956       NA    
U2.time     -0.0027260  0.0006178  -4.412       NA    
U3.time      0.0050112  0.0020535   2.440       NA    
U4.time     -0.0041930  0.0019796  -2.118       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.02407 on 22 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-Squared: 0.9858,  Adjusted R-squared: 0.9799 

Boot restarting based on 6 samples. Last fit:
Convergence *not* attained in 1 iterations (rel. change 0.062135)
```

If I set number of bootstrap samples and the maximum number of iterations, then I can get the outputs to align.

```
out.lm <- lm(y ~ time, data=data_plant)

os <- selgmented(out.lm, type="bic", Kmax=5, control=seg.control(n.boot=1000, it.max = 5))
o <- segmented(out.lm, npsi=4, control=seg.control(n.boot=1000, it.max = 5))

> summary(os)

        ***Regression Model with Segmented Relationship(s)***

Call: 
segmented.lm(obj = olm, seg.Z = seg.Z, psi = startpsi[[i - 1]], 
    control = control1)

Estimated Break-Point(s):
              Est. St.Err
psi1.time 300.220 14.015
psi2.time 469.728 15.680
psi3.time 542.613  9.245
psi4.time 565.911  7.164

Meaningful coefficients of the linear terms:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.0519970  0.0307320   1.692    0.105    
time         0.0025830  0.0001437  17.971 1.23e-14 ***
U1.time     -0.0015229  0.0002118  -7.190       NA    
U2.time     -0.0031220  0.0011670  -2.675       NA    
U3.time      0.0056947  0.0022612   2.518       NA    
U4.time     -0.0043988  0.0019571  -2.248       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.0238 on 22 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-Squared: 0.9861,  Adjusted R-squared: 0.9804 

Convergence *not* attained in 5 iterations (rel. change 0.00043136) 

> summary(o)

        ***Regression Model with Segmented Relationship(s)***

Call: 
segmented.lm(obj = out.lm, npsi = 4, control = seg.control(n.boot = 1000, 
    it.max = 5))

Estimated Break-Point(s):
              Est. St.Err
psi1.time 300.220 14.015
psi2.time 469.728 15.680
psi3.time 542.613  9.245
psi4.time 565.911  7.164

Meaningful coefficients of the linear terms:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.0519970  0.0307320   1.692    0.105    
time         0.0025830  0.0001437  17.971 1.23e-14 ***
U1.time     -0.0015229  0.0002118  -7.190       NA    
U2.time     -0.0031220  0.0011670  -2.675       NA    
U3.time      0.0056947  0.0022612   2.518       NA    
U4.time     -0.0043988  0.0019571  -2.248       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.0238 on 22 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-Squared: 0.9861,  Adjusted R-squared: 0.9804 

Boot restarting based on 12 samples. Last fit:
Convergence attained in 4 iterations (rel. change 2.2993e-12)
```

However, changing the parameters with `seg.control` does not seem to work will all examples. Part of that may be due to my unfamiliarity with the specifics of these parameters.

Here is a second example from my own dataset (time series) where the breakpoints are noticeably different between the two functions. I am unable to modify the parameters to get the outputs to align.

```
x <- c(0, 43, 156, 238, 254, 323, 674, 870, 1193, 1555, 1926, 2279, 2660, 3103, 3479, 3832, 4214, 4929, 5665, 6401, 7122, 7850, 9314, 10062, 11151, 11869)
y <- c(7.31322039, 7.32974969, 6.85224257, 7.11882625, 6.56526497, 6.13122649, 6.30991828, 5.88610403, 4.78749174, 3.76120012, 4.02535169, 4.09434456, 2.23216263, 1.97685495, 2.86789890, 2.80336038, 1.28093385, 0.53062825, 0.83290912, 1.02961942, 0.64185389, 0.18232156, 0.09531018, 0.09531018, 0.33647224, 0.51282363)

out.lm2 <- lm(y ~ x)

os2 <- selgmented(out.lm2, type="bic", Kmax=5)
o2 <- segmented(out.lm2, npsi=2)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot.segmented(os2)
plot.segmented(os2, res=TRUE, add=TRUE, conf.level=0.95, shade=TRUE)
plot.segmented(o2)
plot.segmented(o2, res=TRUE, add=TRUE, conf.level=0.95, shade=TRUE)
```

[comparison of `segmented` and `selgmented` piecewise regressions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biX6Q.gif)

I appreciate any feedback on why the outputs of the `segmented` and `selgmented` functions differ and how to modify that if possible.

Comment: Here is the research paper which explains selgmented https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343737604_Selecting_number_of_breakpoints_in_segmented_regression_implementation_in_the_R_package_segmented